# What is a word for guy who is popular with the ladies?

Tags: single-word-requests

I can't think of another word other than 'ladies man'

Comment: Popular in what way?

Comment: @Sumelic - as in he attracts of a lot of female attention

Answer (score 0):

I think that the word "[Adonis](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/adonis)", may be an effective replacement for ladies man.

Adonis-

Noun

2.
a very handsome young man.

Answer (score 0):

Consider *Adonis*, *Casanova*, *Don Juan*, *Romeo*, *lady-killer*, *lecher*, *libertine*, *philanderer*, *rake*, or *stud*.

Comment: -1 Here are my reasons for down-voting this answer, which is *not* wrong but it is only a list of words: for not mentioning  the differences between these terms, for not saying which have more positive/negative connotations, for not mentioning your source (probably Google Dictionaries.)